# unexpected result at python

Tags: python, output, runtime-error

I tried to print a factor of a number using Python. i.e if input value is `24` then the output is `[1,2,2,2,3]`(1*2*2*2*3=24).

But the answer of the below program is `[1,2,3,2,2,2,2]` instead of `[1,2,3,2,2]`

```
def is_prime(i):
    for j in range(2,i+1):
        if(i%j==0):
            break
    if(i==j):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
def fact(a):
    i=2
    while(i<=a):
        if(a%i==0):
            if(is_prime(i)):
                li.append(i)
                a=int(a/i)
                if(a==1):
                    return 
            else:
                fact(a)
        i=i+1
    if(a>=2):
        fact(a)
    return
li=[]
li.append(1)
a=int(input())
fact(a)
print(li)
```

Comment: this is the most unefficient factor decomposing code I ever saw. I suggest that you check codereview.stackexchange.com to find working examples (or even here)

Comment: BTW, 1 is not a prime number, you must not print it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the recursive call:

```
while(i<=a):
    if(a%i==0):
        if(is_prime(i)):
            li.append(i)
            a=int(a/i)
            if(a==1):
                return 
        else:
            fact(a)  # <-- problem
    i=i+1
```

This will call `fact` again for any non-prime factor of `a`, like `4`, `6`, `8` or `12` in the case of `24`. And those calls will again add `2` to the (global) list of results. Instead, remove the recursive call and just continue with the loop. Also, you should change the outermost `if` to `while` so multiple of the same factor can be found.

Also, the call to `is_prime` is redundant, as `i` is already guaranteed to be prime (otherwise `a` would have already been divided by one of `i`'s prime factors), and the `return` is redundant, too. Finally, for this function to be applicable more than just once, I strongly suggest moving the declaration of `li` *inside* the function and returning it at the end.

```
def fact(a):
    li = [1]  # actually, 1 is not a prime factor, though
    i = 2
    while i <= a:
        while a % i == 0:
            li.append(i)
            a = a // i
        i += 1
    return li

li = fact(a)
```

Comment: @krishna Glad I could help. If this fully solved your problem, please consider accepting the answer, to mark the question as being resolved.